# Toothpick inject в конструктор Qualifier параметр

Tags: android, dependency-injection

Я изучаю Toothpick, и столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается внедрить строку в конструктор. Получаю следующую ошибку: `toothpick.locators.NoFactoryFoundException: No factory could be found for class java.lang.String. Check that the class has either a @Inject annotated constructor or contains @Inject annotated members.` Подскажите,что я делаю не так?

```
@Qualifier annotation class ServerEndpoint
```

```
class NetworkModule : Module() {

    init {
        bind(String::class.java).withName(ServerEndpoint::class.java) to BuildConfig.BASE_URL
        bind(Gson::class.java).toInstance(GsonBuilder().create())
        bind(OkHttpClient::class.java).toProvider(OkHttpProvider::class.java)
        bind(Retrofit::class.java).toProvider(RetrofitProvider::class.java)
        bind(ApiService::class.java).toProvider(ApiServiceProvider::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
@InjectConstructor
class RetrofitProvider(
    @field:ServerEndpoint private val baseUrl: String,
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    private val gson: Gson
) : Provider<Retrofit> {

    override fun get(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .build()
}
```

Comment: Возможно вам надо to на toInstance заменииь